# How to show world map with Lizmap

Tags: web-mapping, lizmap

I would like to show world map with Lizmap web client but I don't know how to do. Could you show me how?

I follow this tutorial: http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/lizmapwebclient/Installation_en for install lizmap web client. But I just load a part of world.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the scale that you want and then set up the canvas extent in QGIS
Project --> Project properties --> OWS Server --> WMS Capabilities --> Use current canvas extent

Save it, and open lizmap plugin
Lizmap Plugin --> Map --> Initial Map extent -> Set from project properties

Et Voilà!